# Unexpected blank page from a PHP email script

Tags: php, sql, email, date, format

Ok I have redesigned it its not perfect but it works and tested this in the url and also tested via cronjobs.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>J~Net Birthday Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<body style="background:#0066CC">
<font color="orange" font size="+1">
<center>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', "0");
$id = '';
$email = '';
$numrows = '';
function sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject) {
$from = "admin@jnetscripts.com";
$subject = "Happy Birthday ";
$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$HTML = '
<body style="background:#0066CC">
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
BODY {background-image: url(\'http://www.jnetscripts.com/apps/balance/images/images(9).jpeg\');
background-repeat; }
</STYLE> 
<font color="orange" font size="+1"><center>
<a href="http://www.jnetscripts.com"><img src="http://www.jnetscripts.com/images/logo.png" height="80px" ></img></a>
<p><br>
<p>
Happy Birthday To You!<p> 
Happy Birthday To You!<p>
Happy Birthday To You!<p>
Happy Birthday To You!<p>
<p><br>
Have A Great Day From J~Net<p>
<a href="http://www.jnetscripts.com"><img src="http://www.jnetscripts.com/images/logo.png" height="80px" ></img></a>';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$boundary = uniqid("HTMLEMAIL");
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".
"boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(strip_tags($HTML)));
// Now we attach the HTML version
$headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($HTML));
if (mail($to,$subject,"",$headers)) {
global $success;
$success++;
}
}
$now = date("d-m-y");
$out  = array('-');
$in = array('');
$new_now = str_replace($out, $in, $now);
$new_now = substr($new_now, 0, 4);
echo 'Todays Date Without The Year Is ';
echo $new_now;
echo '<p>';
require_once("../php_includes/db_conx.php");
$sql = "SELECT id, username, email, dob FROM users WHERE instr(dob, '$new_now') >0";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
if($query){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$email = $row['email'];
$username = $row['username'];
}
if (sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$email,$subject)) {
echo 'No Birthdays today!';
} else {
echo 'Messages Sent';
}
}
?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have posted this to help others who may want the date formatted in there database in UK English Format (the correct way).
Soon i can answer my own questions (need more rep) please vote up so i dont have to edit original sections!

Comment: I don't see a return statement from `sendHTMLemail()` could this be the issue?

Comment: Proper indenting would make your code much more readable. BTW, you're using `mysqli_connect` and then use `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: When you run the script do you see either message "Message Sent" or "No Birthdays Today"? If not you may not have errors turned on. In which case put this at the top of the page `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` where you run the function, it must be in php tags outside the function if run on the same page.

Comment: That code is HIDEOUSLY inefficient. Generate a full-blown data string, then use string operations to change how that string is formatted? Why not simply have `date('dm')` to begin with? Any why are you storing dates as strings? You should be using native mysql date/datetime fields, which allow DIRECT month/day-type comparisons without having to mangle strings the way you are.

Answer (score 0):

The way you get the `$new_now` variable is just magical. You add dashes, then you create arrays with a single key and then replace the dashes with nothing.. Just use `$now = date("dmy");` and you're done.

Now I dont know what the storage type is you use for the `DOB` column in the database. But if its `date` or `datetime` its not going to work. If its `varchar` then it could work. I'm wondering though why you would use `FIND_IN_SET` if you are checking for a column in the same table. You could just use `WHERE dob='".$new_now."'` if its a varchar.

If the column type is `DATE` that would still work, but you should change your `$new_now` to `date("Y-m-d")` or `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` for `DATETIME` (although datetime that would be a problem if the birthday is stored at 09:03 and the script runs at 12:48)

UPDATE:

Just read it again and I missed the `$new_now = substr($new_now, 0, 4);` part. You are just checking for month/day (obviously). So if the `dob` field is varchar, then you can use

```
$new_now = date("dm"); //day and month, both with leading 0
"SELECT username, email, dob FROM users WHERE dob LIKE '".$new_now."%'";
```

Comment: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in /var/www/bday/test2.php on line 48 is the error im getting and the sql is used as i cant have it match the year part so it will be a part match else it wont work unless it is there actual bday with the year so it needs to match the day and month and not the year (there is no time in the dob feild just day month and year which i cant take out as i use it to calculate other things like age etc.

Comment: @MultiMedia Again, you get that error because you use `mysqli_connect` and then a `mysql_*` function.

Comment: iv tried both mysql and mysqli and it is varchar that dob is stored in so i have no idea how to get this working! i get error  Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/test2.php on line 50

Comment: @MultiMedia You don't need `mysqli_select_db` if you pass the DB name as the fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect`. At least don't mix functions from both APIs!